# How do you set two docker containers from the same docker-compose to communicate with one another using HTTP-Get?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

Okay so we have this C# .net core app going on, which has 3 parts. Each part communicates through HTTP requests.  The docker-compose starts all 3 parts

Using postman, we're able to use dbconn directly and successfully connect to the db.
However, we can't go from the app to the dbconn. If we make a GET request from deployUS to connDB, it throws an error saying :

`---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (dbconn:5002)`

This is our docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  job:
    container_name: "job"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Job/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - "5003:80"

  dbconn:
    container_name: "dbconn"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ConnDB/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - "5002:80"
    depends_on:
       - database

  deploy:
    container_name: "deploy"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Deploy/Dockerfile
    # command: docker run -p 5002:5002
    ports:
       - "5001:80"
    depends_on:
       - dbconn

  database:
    container_name: "database"
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
       - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=deploy
       - POSTGRES_DB=deploy_DB
    volumes:
       - ./DB/init-script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-script.sql
       - deploy-databse:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
       - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  deploy-database:
```

Note: The dbconn container is called with http://dbconn:5002

Is there a way that I can tell my containers to talk to one another? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: `5002` is the port used on the host-machine to access the container. The port opened on the container is `80`. so change `5002` to `80`.

Comment: For those who wonder and come up to this thread in the future, I found the problem and the reason this wasn't working was because I had to use http://dbconn as the http address (dbconn is the container name in the docker-compose), without specifying any port. Otherwise, it doesn't work.

Comment: The reason that using the hostname without specifying a port works is because 80 is the default HTTP port.  By not specifying a port, your HTTP client is assuming port 80.  Explicitly specifying port 80 would work as well.